# Using FindAndModify to run queries in the official Mongo Go Driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, mongo-go

In the community driven Mongo driver for Go, i.e. Mgo, we can use the `Apply` API call to run MongoDB queries involving `$set` or `$inc`. An example of this use-case in Mgo is as follows:

```
change := mgo.Change{
    Update:    bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"phone": "+55 53 8402 8510"}},
    ReturnNew: true,
}
_, err = MongoSession.DB("test").C("people").Find(bson.M{"_id": a}).Apply(change, &result)
```

Quoting the official [documentation](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.Apply) for this API call:

> Apply runs the findAndModify MongoDB command, which allows updating,
>   upserting or removing a document matching a query and atomically
>   returning either the old version (the default) or the new version of
>   the document (when ReturnNew is true).

I am currently working on porting a project from [Mgo](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo) to the [official Mongo Go driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver). However, I am unable to find any method that runs the findAndModify command to achieve a similar use-case. For replacing the Apply API with a relevant method from the official driver, what would be the recommended approach?

I have considered examining the query under 'Update' in the existing code, and manually using the Find/Update/Replace methods provided in the official driver. But, would there be any better way to do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the [FindOneAndUpdate](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.FindOneAndUpdate) API.

It internally uses `FindAndModify`, even though it is not explicitly mentioned in the documentations. Code I used to emulate this feature of Mgo in Go's Mongo Driver is as follows:

```
MongoSession, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
err = MongoSession.Connect(ctx)
collection := MongoSession.Database("test").Collection("people")
a, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex("XXXXXXXXXX") //hiding hex value
b := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(ctx, bson.M{"_id": a}, bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"phone": "Replacing using the query"}})
```

Edit (29/02/20): It looks like after this answer, the MongoDB Engineers have updated the [documentation](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) about the MongoDB functionality being used. The documentation now states that `FindOneAndUpdate` uses the `findAndModify` operation.